# Java time: starts at 1th January 1970 at 1am?

Tags: java, date, time

What am I missing? Date() is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970. Should midnight not start at 0am?

**References:**

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html

**My test program:**

```
package be.test.package.time;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TimeWork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");

        //Now
        Date now = new Date();
        strings.add(formatter.format(now));

        //Test dates
        strings.add("01-01-1970 00:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1970 01:00:00.000");
        strings.add("31-11-1969 00:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-2014 00:00:00.000");

        //Test data
        longs.add(-1L);
        longs.add(0L);
        longs.add(1L);
        longs.add(7260000L);
        longs.add(1417706084037L);
        longs.add(-7260000L);

        //Show the long value of the date
        for (String string: strings) {
            try {
                Date date = formatter.parse(string);
                System.out.println("Formated date : " + string + " = Long = " + date.getTime());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Show the date behind the long
        for (Long lo : longs) {
            Date date = new Date(lo);
            String string = formatter.format(date);
            System.out.println("Formated date : " + string + " = Long = " + lo);        
        }
    }
}
```

**This are the results:**

```
Formated date : 05-12-2014 08:54:59.318 = Long = 1417766099318
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:00:00.000 = Long = -3600000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 01:00:00.000 = Long = 0
Formated date : 31-11-1969 00:00:00.000 = Long = -2682000000
Formated date : 01-01-2014 00:00:00.000 = Long = 1388530800000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 12:59:59.999 = Long = -1
Formated date : 01-01-1970 01:00:00.000 = Long = 0
Formated date : 01-01-1970 01:00:00.001 = Long = 1
Formated date : 01-01-1970 03:01:00.000 = Long = 7260000
Formated date : 04-12-2014 04:14:44.037 = Long = 1417706084037
Formated date : 31-12-1969 10:59:00.000 = Long = -7260000
```

Why is:

```
Formated date : 01-01-1970 01:00:00.000 = Long = 0
```

***This is at 1am. I was expecting 0am.***

Comment: What is your timezone ?

Comment: My timezone is CET - Brussels/Belgium time.

Comment: You're ahead of your own times :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

January 1 1970 at midnight UTC. You need the `TimeZone` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Output is

```
01-01-1970 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: When I don't set the TimeZone in the `Calendar` instance, I get the same result. But does that mean, that `DateFormat` is depending on the time zone ?

Comment: @GameDroids Remember that a `Calendar` is a fancy structure on top of the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 @ 12:00.000 ; Yes, `DateFormat` includes the `TimeZone` you might need to know what time it is where you are when it's 3 pm where I am.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I checked the calendar string at it was set to `HOUR_OF_DAY=1`, so `DateFormat` must have converted it back to `UTC` time.

Answer (score 3):

The time represented by the long 0 is midnight 1/1/1970 UTC.  This happens to be 1am 1/1/1970 CET.  But since you're using a `SimpleDateFormat` whose timezone is set to CET,

- 1/1/1970 1am is the time that gets displayed when you format the date;
- parsing 1/1/1970 1am gives you the time represented by long 0.

If you had a `SimpleDateFormat` whose timezone was set to UTC, the behaviour would be entirely different.

You can use the `setTimeZone` method of `DateFormat` if you want to use a timezone other than CET.

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers are correct.

## *java.time*

By the way, this kind of date-time work is much easier using either the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the [*java.time* package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (inspired by *Joda-Time*). Both of these libraries have date-time classes which have a clearly assigned time zone (unlike `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar`).

Both *Joda-Time* and *java.time* use the same [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)): `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

Both use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats when generating a textual representation of their date-time values.

## Joda-Time

In Joda-Time 2.7.

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime( 0 , DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

## java.time

In java.time of Java 8 Update 45.

### `OffsetDateTime`

The [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class represents a moment as seen through an offset from UTC of a certain number of hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime epoch = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( Instant.EPOCH , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> 1970-01-01T00:00Z

### `Instant`

More simply, use the constant [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH).

```
System.out.println( Instant.EPOCH.toString() ) ;
```

> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

To see that that same moment through the offset used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.EPOCH.atZone( z ) ;  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
System.out.println( zdt.toString() ) ;
```

We can see that at the moment of the epoch reference date-time, the people in the Americas were still in the previous year, 1969 versus 1970. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

> 1969-12-31T19:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

See this *java.time* code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RjLXIm).

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).